# I want to display images in a github repo for people to view

Tags: image, repository, responsive-images

I'm currently creating a repository for a fangame community. This repository will feature downloadable resources people can use for modding their games. These include portraits, animations, and other such things.

I am currently in the process of switching over to Github from Gdrive, since it doesn't suit my purposes anymore. This is my repository:

https://github.com/Klokinator/Fire-Emblem-Graphics-Repository

Just as one example, if you navigate to the Portrait Repository folder, you can see all sorts of user-created images people have submitted. However, due to github's limitations, you can only click them one at a time to see the images.

https://github.com/Klokinator/Fire-Emblem-Graphics-Repository/tree/main/Portrait%20Repository/FE10%20Mugs%20(Radiant%20Dawn)

Instead of seeing a list, like so:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MastL.png

I would like people to actually see and be able to browse these images at a glance, like so:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1QuA.png

Is there a github browser extension or other tool that would make this possible? Certainly, power users can clone the repo and browse the images that way, but some people live in countries where downloading the images would take a lot of bandwidth, there might be other issues, etc. I would like to offer them any possible alternatives.

I already have a few extensions that I can link which will let people download single folders or files one by one, rather than downloading the entire repo. It's only viewing images that is causing me issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could automate a process generating a `README.md` Markdown file in each folder, showing all images.

The Markdown file would be automatically shown by GitHub, but after the list of files of the current folder.

Here's an example Node.js script to generate this:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const ROOT_DIR = './Portrait Repository/FE10 Mugs (Radiant Dawn)/';
const README_FILENAME = 'README.md';
const NB_IMAGES_PER_LINE = 4;
let nbImages = 0;
let mdContent = '<table><tr>';

fs.readdirSync(ROOT_DIR).forEach((image) => {
  if (image !== README_FILENAME) {
    if (!(nbImages % NB_IMAGES_PER_LINE)) {
      if (nbImages > 0) {
        mdContent += `
</tr>`;
      }
      mdContent += `
<tr>`;
    }
    nbImages++;
    mdContent += `
<td valign="bottom">
<img src="./${image}" width="200"><br>
${image}
</td>
`;
  }
});
mdContent += `
</tr></table>`;

fs.writeFileSync(path.join(ROOT_DIR, README_FILENAME), mdContent);
```

And here's an example of what it produces:
https://github.com/nhoizey/nicolas-hoizey.com/tree/main/src/assets/logos#readme

Comment: And what about automatic generation with GitHub actions https://towardsdatascience.com/create-a-simple-continuous-integration-ci-for-medium-rss-feed-in-github-profile-readme-b5dc6fdf6315

Comment: Oh wow, I thought for sure nobody would answer, but you not only answered, you provided code! That is super helpful, thank you!

Is there a way to get this to auto-run whenever I activate the repo, then to make the README file for all internal folders?

Comment: As @karlcow suggests, you can use a GitHub action to automate a refresh of the files every time you change something. I don't have the code for this, but the link above can help.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your help! You really went above and beyond for a stranger :)

Comment: That's the spirit of SO! 

Comment: @NicolasHoizey - How can this code executed? I havent coded in years/ executed using GitHub. How can I pull this off for various GH folders / projects I come across?

Comment: @AlexS I run this code once per folder, but it could be changed to manage multiple folders. I run it on my computer and then commit the result, but as karlcow suggested, it could be run in a GitHub Action.

Comment: @NicolasHoizey - Which means I would need a GitHub client on local machine? Need to do it on some non-dev machines to show images. Can I execute it from within Browser - and if so how i.e. GitHub Action? Sorry for asking such a simple thing.

Comment: @AlexS you need a git client to interact with code hosted on GitHub, not necessarily a GitHub specific client. How do you plan to work on GitHub content without any client?